# how to show most popular document libraries in SPO across Site colln

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library

I am working with SharePoint online and have a requirement to show most popular document libraries in the entire site collection. We are using Classic UI so not looking to switch to modern for this functionality.

So if someone implemented any solution, please share how it can be leveraged in SPO.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hos do you define "popular", most added/changed files within the last 24 hours or something else?

Comment: Yes pretty much that should be the explanation.

Comment: Have you achieved that using the Content Search web part? I'm checking to see how things are going there. If this answered your question, please accept it as the best answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a Content Search web part.

Change the query:

Switch to Advanced mode, use `contentclass:"STS_List_DocumentLibrary"` to restrict your search to get document libraries only. Learn more about [contentclass](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mvpawardprogram/2015/02/16/sharepoint-power-searching-using-contentclass/).

[image]

Open the "Sorting" tab, sort the results by "LastModifiedTime".

[image]

Change the number of items to show:

[image]

Note:

There are several crawled properties for saving the modified date are mapped to "LastModifiedTime" managed property in SharePoint. Read [this article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/spses/2013/10/30/show-more-relevant-titles-in-search-results-in-sharepoint-2013-plus-some-other-improvements/) for more information (same in SPO). It may cause the "LastModifiedTime" uses incorrect time.

For the default “Modified” column that contains the last modified date and time information in the list/library, you can move up “ows_Modified” crawl property to the top of the mappings for “LastModifiedTime” managed property. Or, you can create a managed property, map “ows_Modified” crawl property to this managed property and use this managed property instead of “LastModifiedTime” managed property in display template. Run a full crawl after changing managed properties or add new ones.

[How to manage search schema in SharePoint Online](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Manage-the-search-schema-in-SharePoint-Online-d4fab46d-ba41-4c03-9d4c-32b5b33198b6)

Comment: Thanks but I think you misunderstood my question, I am looking to display library names that are popular not document names. So its like showing top 5 library names which have been used most for document upload, edit etc in last 24 hours. Any thoughts?

Comment: I changed my answer. please check

Comment: great thanks Joanna, I will test this out.